# installing avr gcc

Tags: installation

When I tried to install avr gcc on my ubuntu then it says internet connection error.Though all the connections are ok.And installing arduino IDE also seems to be a problem because the same thing happens.

Comment: **Exactly** what is it that you see? what is the *exact* message you get.

Comment: How exactly do you know that the connections are ok?

Comment: And **how** are you trying to install the software? Please provide the commands and the output (in an edit to your question)

Comment: well,i tried to install avr gcc and avr libc and also checked for the updates .As soon as i click install in ubuntu software center then it shows internet connection error.Regarding my problem on checking for updates,only half of the updates are installed and then it showed internet connection error.if there was internet connection error then why web pages would open!

Comment: when installing IDE it gives something like this
Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libftdi/libftdi1_0.19-4_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libj/libjna-java/libjna-java_3.2.7-4_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rxtx/librxtx-java_2.2pre2-10_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/binutils-avr/binutils-avr_2.20.1-2_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
........